# How to get the url which the browser is current visiting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macruby

I want to implement a tiny app that can save the current url opening in the browser to delicious. So the first thing to do is get the url. So what function/class can we use to get the curl in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AppleScript; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263741/using-applescript-to-grab-the-url-from-the-frontmost-window-in-web-browsers-the) for scripts for a variety of browsers.

Comment: Is there any exist cocoa api can do that ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html