# Tracking browser actions from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari, osx-snow-leopard

I would be opening a URL from objective-c in a MAC OS X Application ( safari would suffice).

But, I want to know if the user closes the tab or navigates to other page or submits it.
So that I can take a corrective action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I could offer involves AppleScripting and/or Apple Events.

Open up Safari in Script Editor and take a look at the dictionary of possibilities.  Safari doesn't have a way of sending other applications notifications when things change in relation to its windows, but you can poll* Safari periodically from your app to see what the current URL associated with each window is.

Check out [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263741/using-applescript-to-grab-the-url-from-the-frontmost-window-in-web-browsers-the) to see how people are grabbing the URL from the frontmost window in various web browsers.  And these answers can likely be extended to cover **all** windows.

* yes, I do realize that polling is a "bad thing" in terms of programming these days.  Until Safari can be told to do notifications to other apps, polling is the only way I can think of.